# Facebook JS API - Facebook Javascript API - how to get permissions for Facebook API of the logged in user?

Tags: permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I get the Facebook app permissions for the logged in user using Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the API call is `/me/permissions`:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/